# how do i make dynamically created elements draggable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I'm trying to figure out how to make dynamically created divs draggable, so I've created [this very simple thing](http://jsfiddle.net/carriecoxwell/m3BXZ/7/) to help me. I understand that I have to use the on() event with a non-dynamic handler. By having the body element handle the cloning event in the linked JSfiddle, I've succeeded in making the dynamically created divs clonable, but they are not draggable. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for the help!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '.pink', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl pink'></div>"))
    });
    $("body").on('click', '.blue', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl blue'></div>"))
    });
    $("body").on('click', '.coral', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl coral'></div>"))
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

Comment: u r not putting class 'draggable' in the element

Comment: wow, good catch. i can't believe i missed that. i feel silly!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

at time of creation put class "draggable" or id in the element. (you are not putting class) and then code should work

```
$('.container').append($("<div class='bl pink draggable'></div>"));
$('.draggable').draggable()
```

Comment: What when ids are multiple?

Comment: put class in the element to run

Comment: Or inline: `$('.container').append($("<div class='bl pink draggable'></div>").draggable());`

Comment: i have use after : $("#" + appendID).after(NewDropPanelv).droppable();

Answer (score 10):

I would do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m3BXZ/9/)

I'm calling the `draggable` method after I add the elements to the container, like this:

```
 $("<div class='bl pink'></div>").appendTo('.container').draggable();
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. The accepted answer certainly works, but I was looking for a cleaner, more centralized solution. I didn't want to explicitly call .draggable() every place my script inserted new elements.

What I settled on was listening for DOM inserts on the parent element and then applying .draggable() on the inserted children. For example:

```
$("#Parent").on("DOMNodeInserted", ".ChildClass", function() { $(this).draggable(); });
```

Check out this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hL7u95L/

Comment: Please note that `DOMNodeInserted` and other mutation events are deprecated: ["Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Answer (score 4):

use

```
$("<div class='bl blue'></div>").draggable().appendTo($('.container'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3BXZ/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.container').on('click', '.pink', function () {
        $("<div class='bl blue'></div>").draggable().appendTo($('.container'));
    });

    $('.container').on('click', '.blue', function () {
        $("<div class='bl blue'></div>").draggable().appendTo($('.container'));
    });
    $('.container').on('click', '.coral', function () {
        $("<div class='bl coral'></div>").draggable().appendTo($('.container'));
    });

    $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

[.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: You don't need to pass a jquery element to appendTo

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. It's just not necessary/wrong, you're creating an instance without the need for one

Answer (score 3):

Add draggable class to the dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '.pink', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl pink draggable'></div>"));
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });
    $("body").on('click', '.blue', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl blue draggable'></div>"));
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });
    $("body").on('click', '.coral', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl coral draggable'></div>"));
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });

});
```

Comment: Same as @Harry answer, this could be a problem if you want specific behaviour for each element

Comment: Then use a specific ID for each one. $('.container').append($("<div class='bl coral' id="someid"></div>"));
        $("#someid").draggable();

Comment: Or, you can check my answer

Comment: i have use after  : $("#" + appendID).after(NewDropPanelv).droppable(); but not work my div droppable

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the below way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.container').on('click', '.pink', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl pink draggable'></div>"));
        $('.draggable').draggable();
    });

    $('.container').on('click', '.blue', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl blue draggable'></div>"));
        $('.draggable').draggable();
    });
    $('.container').on('click', '.coral', function () {
        $('.container').append($("<div class='bl coral draggable'></div>"));
        $('.draggable').draggable();
    });
    $('.draggable').draggable();

});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/m3BXZ/11/)

Comment: With this you're recalling `draggable()` on the allready draggable elements. This could be a problem if you want specific behaviour for each element

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by *specific behavior on each element*. The requirement is just to make the dynamic elements also draggable only right?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I meant that you may want to call `draggable` with different options, and doing `$('.draggable').draggable([options]);` will do it on each element, instead of the new one. It's not wrong by any means, I was just pointing it out

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: No worries mate, its not wrong to improve/point out items :) I now get what you meant. In that case, we can attach an `id` to the `div` or have a specific `class` for each unique behavior and modify the `.draggable` call as required.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Btw, +1 for your sample and the others. I see many of us have posted working options at more or less the same time. OP can accept only one though :)

Answer (score 3):

Ive added some bits to your fiddle hopefully it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/m3BXZ/8/

Basically Ive made a function called startDrag that makes the new blocks draggable:

```
function startDrag(){
    $(".bl").draggable();
}
```

Theres many ways to do this its just finding which solution suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example):

```
       $('.btn-hotspot-add').click(function(){
            //Create element and append draggable action
            var element = $('<span class="hotspot"></span>').draggable({
                'containment': "parent",
                'stop': function(elm){
                    //Sample stop action
                    var parentWith = elm.target.offsetParent.offsetWidth;
                    var parentHeight = elm.target.offsetParent.offsetHeight;
                    var x = elm.target.offsetLeft;
                    var y = elm.target.offsetTop;
                    console.log(parentWith+'x'+parentHeight+' - '+x+'x'+y );

                }
            });

            //Append draggable element to parent container
            $('#parent').append(element);
        });
```