# Enabling draggable event on dynamically created jquery ui draggables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, user-interface

One of the solutions came close, it allowed me to add the drag event but threw my dragged item across the page on drop.

I am pasting my code that I have below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var item_count = $('#drag').children().size();
    var matched = false;

$(".drag").draggable({
        revert:"invalid",
        helper:'clone',
        stop:function(event,ui){
                content = 'This drop starts at :'+ ($("#drop_container :first-child a:nth-of-type(2)").text())+'</br>';
                content += 'This drop finishes at :'+ ($("#drop_container :last-child a:nth-of-type(3)").text())+'</br>';


            $('.info').empty();
            var amount = 0;
            var distance = 0;
            content += 'This Drop contains <strong>'+ ($('#drop_container').children().size()) + '</strong> Orders</br>';
            $('#drop_container').children('div').each(function() {
                    amount += $(this).data('weight');
                    distance += $(this).data('est_distance');
            });  

            content += 'The combined weight for this drop is: '+ amount +' Kilograms</br>';
            content += 'The Estimated Travel Distance is: ' + distance + ' Kilometers</br>';
            $(".info").html(content);

            //get order_id, siteid and collection date
            var orderid = $('#drop_container :first-child').attr('id');
            //alert('order : '+orderid + ' | Site ID : '+ siteid + ' | date : '+colldate);
            $.post('<?php echo site_url("schedules/matchingdrops");?>',{'id': orderid },
                function(data){

                    if ('false'){
                        $('#drag').empty();
                var reset_link = '<a href="#" id="reset_list">No more ORDERS to process, Click to reset list</a>';
                $('#drag').append(reset_link);
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                //alert(data);
            });
    }
});

$(".drop").droppable({
    tolerance:"pointer",
    drop:function(event,ui){

        if (ui.draggable.attr("id") === 'box2'){
            ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
        }else{

            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
            var new_count = $('#drop_container').children().size();
            if(item_count == new_count){

                var reset_link = '<a href="#" id="reset_list">No more ORDERS to process, Click to reset list</a>';
                $('#drag').append(reset_link);
            }
        }

    }
});

$('#drag').on("click","#reset_list",function(){

    $.post("<?php echo site_url('schedules/get_orders_reset');?>",function(response){

    var cc = ''; 

       $.each(response,function(key,val){
        cc += "<div class='drag order_box' data-weight='"+val.weight+"' data-qty='"+val.qty+"' data-distance='"+val.est_distance+"' id='"+val.order_id+"'>"
        cc += "<a href='#' id='"+val.order_id+"'> Order No: "+val.order_id+"</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Collection Date: "+val.req_col_time.substr(0,10)+"</br>";
        cc += "Collection Point: <a href='#' id='"+val.site1id+"'>"+val.collection+"</a></br>";
        cc += "Delivery Point: <a href='#' id='"+val.site2id+"'>"+val.destination+"</a></br>";
        cc += "</div>";
        });
       $('#drag').empty();
       $('#drop_container').empty();
       $('.info').empty();
        $('#drag').append(cc);
      },'json');

        });
    });
```

what I need to do is enable dragging within the reset function and have the items placed properly within my container div

adding a sort of working jsfiddle to have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8S8GF/

Comment: thanks for the edit, first time using this site, so making editing mistakes as i go along

Comment: do you want to have draggable on dynamically added elements on your reset function?

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/a/18789446/3159813

Comment: oops sorry I came across this fiddle example which I have implemented successfully on my div elements, what is happening now is the following.

Comment: jeez don't use enter for a new line :(, yes nouphal, the new content must be draggable, like the initial content was. it drags and drops now, but unlike the initial content, the element does not position itself properly within the drop div. Sorry hop i am making sense

Comment: its a style issue. try removing unwanted styles for drag drop elements

Comment: this is the only styling i have applied to the droppable div               .order_box{
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        width:350px;
        position:relative;
        border:2px solid black;
        min-height:25px;
        margin:5px;
    }

Comment: remove position:relative and check

Comment: no luck on removing position relative and how do we continue discussion in chat lol

Comment: Try calling .draggable on the newly-created elements

Comment: i have my append statements setup as $('random_item').append('filler_info').draggable() which allows me to drag the newly created item, but it drops it anywhere on the screen when dropped

Comment: I created an updated fiddle which hopefully does what you need. What basically happens is that the "position:relative" is removed from the draggable element after it has been dropped inside the drop zone.