# Create jquery-ui draggable handles dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I dynamically create a handle for the jquery-ui `.draggable()`?

I have some `contenteditable` divs on the website and I want to make them draggable on the screen. When I use the draggable function, then I can't edit the div. So I need to use a handle:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ handle: ".the_handle" });
```

But the problem is that I can't make the handle manually because the `contenteditable` divs are created dynamically.

How can I create the handle dynamically?

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789354/how-do-i-make-dynamically-created-elements-draggable

Answer (score 1):

The below code should help you out:

HTML

```
<div id="draggable">
  <div id = "editable" contenteditable="true"/>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
dvar draggableDiv = $('#draggable').draggable();

$('#editable', draggableDiv).mousedown(function(ev) {
     draggableDiv.draggable('disable');
}).mouseup(function(ev) {
     draggableDiv.draggable('enable');
});
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cSMYG/1/

*Not what you are looking for? Let me know*