# innerHTML list items dragable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code.when I call init `innerHTML` list item not dragable I don't know where I'm stuck.test1 and test2 is not dragable it possible to drag?

[Live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bPPQE/23/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#accordion ul').append('<li>test1</li><li>test2</li>');
  $( "#accordion li" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid_3 mainwindow formfields">
    <h3>Available Fields</h3>
    <div id="accordion">
         <ul>
            <li>First Name</li>
            <li>Last Name</li>  
            <li>Company</li>            
         </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oowg1xpr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work see the snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#accordion ul').append('<li>test1</li><li>test2</li>');
  $("#accordion li").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <div class="grid_3 mainwindow formfields">
    <h3>Available Fields</h3>
    <div id="accordion">
      <ul>
        <li>First Name</li>
        <li>Last Name</li>
        <li>Company</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery before jquery ui and it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#accordion li" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid_3 mainwindow formfields">
    <h3>Available Fields</h3>
    <div id="accordion">
         <ul>
            <li>First Name</li>
            <li>Last Name</li>  
            <li>Company</li>            
         </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok JC Dev see now i add some tag using innerhtml like $(document).ready(function(){ $('#accordion ul').append('<li>test1</li>')
  $( "#accordion li" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
}); but test1 is not dragable how it's possible

Comment: Then your case might be the duplicate issue of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789354/how-do-i-make-dynamically-created-elements-draggable

Answer (score 0):

You need to import correct jquery and jquery-ui files.

It works.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/djogf3g9/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#accordion li" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});
```

Get your files here
https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion li" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid_3 mainwindow formfields">
    <h3>Available Fields</h3>
    <div id="accordion">
         <ul>
            <li>First Name</li>
            <li>Last Name</li>  
            <li>Company</li>            
         </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```