# Appending <li> to a <ul> but not becoming draggable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to have a user build a list of sports, then have that list of sport list items be dragged into a "cart". But any of the appended list items do not become draggable and I'm not too sure why or how to make them so.
The placeholder list item is able to be dragged but not any of the appended ones.

```js
/* JS code for sports.html */


$(function () {
    // initialization code when DOM is ready

    //hides the second step
    $('#step2').hide();

    //tooltips
    $('#addSport').tooltip();

    //array of the auto completed sports
    var tags = ["archery", "badminton", "baseball", "softball", "football", "soccer", "volleyball", "basketball", "golf", "hockey", "swimming", "running", "track and field", "gymnastics", "dance", "rowing", "tennis", "wrestling", "weightlifting", "karate", "lacrosse", "cricket", "polo", "skating", "shooting", "handball", "fencing", "cycling", "boxing", "cheerleading", "surfing", "snowboarding", "dodgeball", "jujutso", "sumo", "taekwondo", "paintball", "pocket billiards", "pool", "fishing", "skiing", "sailing", "luge", "bobsleigh", "racquetball"];
    $("#sportName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(tags, function (item) {
                return matcher.test(item);
            }));
        }
    });

    var sportClick = 0;
    $("#addSport").click(function () {
        sportClick++;
        var sport;
        sport = $("#sportName").val();
        
        //takes the first sport and replaces the holding text
        if (sportClick === 1) {
            $("#sportList").html('<li>' + sport + '</li>');
            //$("#sportList").html(sport + '<br>');
        } 
        //any other sports will be added to the first
        else {
            $("#sportList").append('<li>' + sport + '</li>');
            //$("#sportList").append(sport + '<br>');
        }
    });

    //allows the sport items become draggable
    $("#sportList li").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    }).css("cursor", "pointer");

    $("#step2Btn").click(function () {
        $('#step2').show();
    });

    //allows the sport items to be dropped into the cart
    $("#cart").droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        drop: function (evt, ui) {
            var obj;
            $("#cart").css("height", "auto");
            obj = ui.draggable;
            console.log("dropped!");
            $("#cart").append("<li>" + obj.html() +
                " (<a href='dummy.html' class='remove'>Remove</a>)" +
                "</li>");
        }
    });

    //able to remove a sport item
    $("#cart").on("click", "a.remove", function () {
        console.log("Remove element!");
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });

    getCart = function () {
        var cartList, el, group1;
        cartList = [];
        $("#cart li").each(function () {
            el = $(this).html();
            console.log("Matching element " + el);
            group1 = el.match(/^(.+) \(<a href/)[1]
            console.log("Match with reg exp: " + group1);
            cartList.push(group1);
        })
        return cartList;
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sports</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #cart {
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: lightgray;
            height: 100px;
            width: 300px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Sports Select</h1>

    <h2>Step 1: Enter in as many sports that you can think of</h2>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Sport Name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" size="15" id="sportName" onfocus="this.value=''" title="Enter a sport name">
        <input type="button" id="addSport" value="Add Sport" title="Click to add a sport" />
    </p>

    <h2>Sports List</h2>
    <ul id="sportList">
        <li>All entered sports will be entered here.</li>
    </ul><br>

    <label><strong>Click to start step 2: </strong></label><br>
    <input type="button" id="step2Btn" value="Step 2" title="Click to show step two" />


    <h2 id="step2">Step 2: Drag all the sports that you've played into the box</h2>
    <br>


    <h2>Cart</h2>
    <ul id="cart">

    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to make new elements draggable too.
Here is how 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789354/how-do-i-make-dynamically-created-elements-draggable

Comment: @jesusnoseq Yes, I just realized that. I just posted an answer to how I fixed my specific issue. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific case, all I did was put the draggable() snippet into the `#addSport` button, which would then add the draggable condition to all of the newly added list items

```
var sportClick = 0;
var sportItem;
$("#addSport").click(function () {
    sportClick++;
    var sport;
    sport = $("#sportName").val();
    sportItem = '<li>' + sport + '</li>';


    //takes the first sport and replaces the holding text
    if (sportClick === 1) {
        $("#sportList").html(sportItem);
        //$("#sportList").html(sport + '<br>');
    }
    //any other sports will be added to the first
    else {
        $("#sportList").append(sportItem);
        //$("#sportList").append(sport + '<br>');
    }

    //allows the sport items become draggable
    $("#sportList li").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    }).css("cursor", "pointer");

    $("#step2Btn").click(function () {
        $('#step2').show();
    });
});
```